# ydotool: first, backend unavailable, then crash on connection

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault, xdotool

I'm using the Linux Mint Debian Edition 5 Linux distro.
I'm usually satisfied of `xdotool` I use since years on linux
but since few weeks by using it with a browser (chromium, firefox), for long times hours scripting (low-level value tasks), it appears that it's crashing the browser, either FF/chrome/qutebrowser.

`xdotool`, especially because it is specific to X11, might be depreciated in favor of the newer tool `ydotool`, which works on both xorg and wayland. So, I'm trying to use `ydotool`

After added my user to `INPUT` group with a specific `module.d` file added,

Then, I launch the `ydotool` daemon, as `root`:

```
ydotoold
```

and it starts.

I just run few times the different commands within the main page of [`ydotool` github page](https://github.com/ReimuNotMoe/ydotool):

```
ydotool key 56:1 62:1 62:0 56:0
ydotool: notice: ydotoold backend unavailable (may have latency+delay issues)
```

but suddently:

```
ydotoold: listening on socket /tmp/.ydotool_socket
ydotoold: accepted client
Erreur de segmentation [segmentation fault] (core dumped)
```

How do I make it work?

Comment: The question in your title is bad; the answer is "yes". That's not what you wanted to know. Please change your question title to reflect what you want to actually have answered – "How do {what you want to do}?" is a good question, which has an answer from which you profit. Also, your question reads like a blog post with unnecessary fluff – it took me three times to read the unrelated stuff than it took me to read the actual technical content. We value short, on-point questions here, so I'll go ahead and do some copyediting on that :)

Comment: please check the link to ydotool's github page I've added whether it's the same you had in mind.

Comment: group names are case-sensitive. Are you sure you added your user to the `INPUT` group, and not to the `input` group?

Comment: Make sure to install the latest version from the developper's website (requires compiling, but it is not difficult). I wrote a howto on compiling and setting up ydotool over on Askubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/a/1413830/558158 which probably will largely work unchanged on Debian as well.